# How to use autocompletion in Chromium with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, json, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, chromium

Im using Windows and trying to use autocompletion with [***you-complete-me***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RichardHe.you-complete-me) extension in VS Code with this guide [Visual Studio Code Dev](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/vscode.md) but then i have issues like this:
[image]

Followed by the [above guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/vscode.md), I tried setting [***you-complete-me***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RichardHe.you-complete-me) in my workspaces settings:

```
"ycmd.path": "C:/Program Files/~/.ycmd",
"ycmd.global_extra_config":"D:/chromium/depot_tools/src/tools/vim/chromium.ycm_extra_conf.py",
"ycmd.confirm_extra_conf": false,
```

Followed by the issue, i generated the compile_command.json file by the following command:

```
ninja -C out/Default -t compdb cc cxx objc objcxx > out/Default/compile_commands.json
```

and then in `c_cpp_properties.json` file, I updated the "includePath", "browse" path and added the path of the above `compile_commands.json` file to "compileCommands" :

```
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include/*",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/atlmfc/include/*",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/winrt",
            "${workSpaceRoot}",
            "D:/chromium/depot_tools/src"
        ],
        "compileCommands": "D:/chromium/depot_tools/src/out/Default/compile_commands.json",
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/include/*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/atlmfc/include/*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.16299.0/winrt",
                "${workSpaceRoot}",
                "D:/chromium/depot_tools/src"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
```

But nothing happens and these issues still appear. Can anyone help me to solve these issues or suggest me a clearly guide to get start with chromium in VS Code?

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time try to make YCM work on Windows but had no luck. However, I am able to make IntelliSense work fairly well. First ensure you have `C/C++` extension installed.

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Win32",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17134.0",
      "compilerPath": "${workspaceFolder}/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang-cl.exe",
      "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/out/Default/compile_commands.json",
      "cStandard": "c11",
      "cppStandard": "c++17",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I use this command to generate compile_commands.json:

```
python tools/clang/scripts/generate_compdb.py -p out/Default -o out/Default/compile_commands.json
```

Besides, I recommend uninstall/disable YCM unless you figure out how to make it work, because it can interfere with C/C++ extension.